# read.csv vs. read.table

Tags: r, file-io, read.table, read.csv

I have seen in several cases that while `read.table()` is not able to read a tab delimited file (for example the annotation table of a microarray) returning the following error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line xxx did not have yyy elements
```

`read.csv()` works perfectly on the same file with no errors. I think also the speed of `read.csv()` is also higher than `read.table()`.

Even more: `read.table()` is doing very crazy reading a file of me. It makes this error while reading line 100, but when I copy and paste lines 90 to 110 just after the head of the same file, it still makes error of line 100+21 (new lines copied at the beginning). If there is any problem with that line, why doesn't it report that error while reading the pasted line at the beginning? I confirm that `read.csv()` reads the same file with no error.

Do you have any idea of why `read.table()` is unable to read the same files that `read.csv()` works on it? Also is there any reason to use `read.table()` in any cases?

Comment: Also read the help page for `read.table()` under memory usage as to why it may appear slow for large files.

Comment: we can't answer your (updated) question without a reproducible example.  The most common reading problems are (1) undetected comment characters, (2) unmatched quotation marks, (3) changes in number of fields per line after the first 5 lines of the file when `fill=TRUE`.  Because `read.csv` and `read.table` have different default values for `comment`, `quote`, and `fill`, any of these could be the problem.

Comment: PS there are 8 combinations of `comment`/`quote`/`fill`: you could experiment with all of them and see how the results differ -- that might lead you to the answer. `count.fields()` is handy for diagnostics too.

Comment: The collective experience of every R expert I've ever encountered has led me to develop a prior for problems like this that basically consists of the [Dirac Delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) function with infinite mass on "there's a weird line/character in your file", not a problem with `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Comment: I am not sure how to share the file on SO

Comment: @joran: yes, but the interaction of `fill` and differing number of fields is so weird that it is a severe "misfeature", maybe even a ((bug)) ... Ali, you generally just have to post your file/share it via one of the many public file-sharing mechanisms ...

Comment: PS @joran, it occurs to me that you probably don't mean "infinite mass", you probably mean "unit mass, infinitely concentrated" (infinite density) ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`read.csv` is a fairly thin wrapper around `read.table`; I would be quite surprised if you couldn't exactly replicate the behaviour of `read.csv` by supplying the correct arguments to `read.table`.  However, some of those arguments (such as the way that quotation marks or comment characters are handled) could well change the speed and behaviour of the function.

In particular, this is the *full* definition of `read.csv`:

```
function (file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", 
    fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...) {
     read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
        dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
}
```

so as stated it's just `read.table` with a particular set of options.

As @Chase states in the comments below, the help page for `read.table()` says just as much under `Details`:

> read.csv and read.csv2 are identical to read.table except for the defaults. They are intended for reading ‘comma separated value’ files (‘.csv’) or (read.csv2) the variant used in countries that use a comma as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator.

Comment: Good answer - I would just add that the help page for `read.table()` says just as much under details `read.csv and read.csv2 are identical to read.table except for the defaults. They are intended for reading ‘comma separated value’ files (‘.csv’) or (read.csv2) the variant used in countries that use a comma as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator.`. So to the OP - yes, you would want `read.table` when your data don't match the default values for `read.csv`

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `read.table` to read tab-delimited files, use `read.delim`.  (It is just a thin wrapper around `read.table` but it sets the options to appropriate values)

Answer (score 0):

`read_table()` does fail sometime on tab `sep`'ed file and setting `sep='\s+'` may help assuming item in your table have no space