# Calculating coefficients of bivariate linear regression

Tags: r, matrix, regression, multiplication

[Question to be answered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Noo6i.png)

Does anyone know how to solve the attached problem in two lines of code? I believe an as.matrix would work to create a matrix, `X`, and then use `X %*% X`, `t(X)`, and `solve(X)` to get the answer. However, it does not seem to be working. Any answers will help, thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. It would be helpful for you to produce a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `read.csv` instead of `read.table`

It would be useful for you to go over the difference of the two functions in this thread: [read.csv vs. read.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828438/read-csv-vs-read-table)

```
df <- read.csv("http://pengstats.macssa.com/download/rcc/lmdata.csv")
model1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)
coefficients(model1) # get the coefficients of your regression model1
summary(model1) # get the summary of model1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @kon_u, here is an example to do it by hands:

```
df <- read.csv("http://pengstats.macssa.com/download/rcc/lmdata.csv")
model1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)
coefficients(model1) # get the coefficients of your regression model1
summary(model1) # get the summary of model1 

### Based on the formula
X <- cbind(1, df$x1, df$x2) # the column of 1 is to consider the intercept
Y <- df$y
bhat <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% Y # coefficients 
bhat # Note that we got the same coefficients with the lm function
```

Comment: Note that this formula allows you to compute coefficients of multivariate linear regressions too.